# How to recreate Sharepoint quick edit button functionality in custom button

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I got rid of the O365 bar and the edit bar (#s4-ribbonrow) on my site for styling purposes. I want the user to still be able to use the functionality that the "quick edit" button provides when they select a list item. How can i implement the same functionality in a custom button on my page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Open SharePoint quick edit mode for view**

SharePoint uses this method :

```
EnsureScriptParams('inplview', 'InitGridFromView', 'VIEW ID');return false;
```

So, your sample anchor element:

```
<a onclick="EnsureScriptParams('inplview', 'InitGridFromView', SP.ListOperation.ViewOperation.getSelectedView());return false;">TEST</a>
```

Use `SP.ListOperation.ViewOperation.getSelectedView()` to get view ID in older sharepoints, or use `_spPageContextInfo.viewId` in SharePoint Online

**Open SharePoint edit item dialog**

Use `SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems()` to get selected items from view.

click button handler should look something like this:

```
if (SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems().length === 1) {
    var itm = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems()[0];
    var _url = _spPageContextInfo.siteServerRelativeUrl + '/' + _spPageContextInfo.layoutsUrl + '/listform.aspx?PageType=6&ListId=' +_spPageContextInfo.pageListId + '&ID=' + itm.id;
    console.log(_url);
    var options = {
        title: "Edit item",
        width: 500,
        height: 600,
        showClose: true,
        allowMaximize: true,
        autoSize: true,
        url: _url
    };
    SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options); 
}
```

The hardest part is generating proper url:

`PageType=6` means editform, value of `4` means dispform

To properly link to `listform.aspx` page you need to use some of `_spPageContextInfo` properties like list id, server relative url and layouts folder url

Comment: I wasn't clear enough in my question. When I click on the quick edit button on my page it toggles between a spreadsheet format and the regular list view where the items in the list are not editable. I don't want to open a dialog, I just want to edit them like a spreadsheet, like the button usually lets you do.

Comment: I don't have the time to test this at the moment, running around at work, but will this still open up a dialog window?